# scrapy spider bypass deny my rules

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

hi im trying to use crawlspider and I created my own deny rules

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider): 
    name = "craigs" 
    allowed_domains = ["careers-cooperhealth.icims.com"] 
    start_urls = ["careers-cooperhealth.icims.com"] 
    d= [0-9] 
    path_deny_base = [ '.(login)', '.(intro)', '(candidate)', '(referral)', '(reminder)', '(/search)',] 
    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(deny = path_deny_base, 
                                     allow=('careers-cooperhealth.icims.com/jobs/…;*')), 
                                     callback="parse_items", 
                                     follow= True), )
```

still my spider crawled pages like https://careers-cooperhealth.icims.com/jobs/22660/registered-nurse-prn/login where login should not be crawled what is the problem here?

Comment: Post your entire spider class.

Comment: class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "craigs"
    allowed_domains = ["careers-cooperhealth.icims.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://careers-cooperhealth.icims.com"]
    d= [0-9]

    path_deny_base = [ '.(login)',
    '.(intro)',
    '(candidate)',
    '(referral)',
    '(reminder)',
    '(/search)',]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(deny = path_deny_base, allow=('https://careers-cooperhealth.icims.com/jobs/'),restrict_xpaths=('*'))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

Comment: Edit it into your question. It's hard to read when it's all in one line.

Comment: how to make it to next line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change it this way (no dots and parenthesis):

```
deny = ['login', 'intro', 'candidate', 'referral', 'reminder', 'search']
allow = ['jobs']

rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(deny = deny, 
                                 allow=allow, 
                                 restrict_xpaths=('*')), 
                                 callback="parse_items", 
                                 follow= True),)
```

That will mean no `login` or `intro` or etc in the extracted link, only extract links that have `jobs` in it.

Here's the whole spider code that crawls the link `https://careers-cooperhealth.icims.com/jobs/intro?hashed=0` and prints 'YAHOO!':

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craigs" 
    allowed_domains = ["careers-cooperhealth.icims.com"] 
    start_urls = ["https://careers-cooperhealth.icims.com"]

    deny = ['login', 'intro', 'candidate', 'referral', 'reminder', 'search']
    allow = ['jobs']

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(deny = deny,
                                     allow=allow,
                                     restrict_xpaths=('*')),
                                     callback="parse_items",
                                     follow= True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        print "YAHOO!"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! that should do it